# How to disable client side validation using jquery on a single field when checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor-pages

This is my html code in MVC's razor page.

```
<form>
 <input id="inputLPR"  asp-for="LicensePlateNo" class="form-control"/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="isEnableBypass"><label for="isEnableBypass">Bypass Checksum</label>
</form>
```

The following is in my javascript and what I have tried.

```
<script>
   var isEnableBypass = false;
   $('#isEnableBypass').change(function () {
     isEnableBypass = this.checked;
        $("#inputLPR").validate({
      ignore: ".ignore"
  })
 });
</script>
```

It still will not bypass the validation after this. Could anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: just update data-val="false" , $("#inputLPR").data("val",false)

Answer (score 0):

*ignore: ".ignore"* will only ignore inputs with the class ignore.
So you need  `<input type="checkbox" class="ignore" id="isEnableBypass">`